# Processing multiple continuous json responses

Tags: java, json

I am currently working on a java client implementation which is able to communicate to a server by sending requests and receive responses via restful api to retrieve movie responses.

I am simulating tests where the client will be receiving responses after a successful request sent to the server.

So for features that responds with a single individual response, it is straightforward to store into a single file and read from it directly.

For example, **single-response.json** file below represents a response where I am able to retrieve a movie detail.

```
{
    result: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Wick",
        movie: "John Wick"
    }
}
```

However, I am facing difficulties when handling continuous json responses where I am receiving. And I receive an error "**JSON standard allows only one top level value**". And the below response is not even a list of responses but rather sent individually and periodically as seen below by the server .

**continuous-response.json file**

```
{
    result: {
        percentage: "0%",
        result: "started movie download"
    }
}

{
    result: {
        percentage: "65%",
        result: "downloading movie in progress"
    }
}

{
    result: {
        percentage: "100%",
        result: "finished download movie"
    }
}
```

So how can I read and process the continous json response during a movie download progress from a file? Or do I have to read it in different separate files instead?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells everything you need to know. The JSON standard *does not allow more than one top level element*.

A common practice i‘ve seen is to use an array as the top level element and add your json objects to that array.

`example.json`

```json
[
    {
        result: {
            percentage: "0%",
            result: "started movie download"
        }
    },
    {
        result: {
            percentage: "65%",
            result: "downloading movie in progress"
        }
    },
    {
        result: {
            percentage: "100%",
            result: "finished download movie"
        }
    }
]
```

If you are using multiple workers make sure to synchronize the file access.

When dealing with many responses and the json file gets very large, and if your method of handling the json object (i.e. the library you use) holds *all* json data you might end up with a lot of memory used.

Also when working with continuous responses from the server, you most probably end up with re-writing the whole json file every time you add a new response to it (again, depends on your library).

Maybe consider using database or flat file storage (e.g. bundling responses into their own file) instead of a single file.